Question about an example on ring theory from Dummit and Foote
Background
Example:  If $p$ is a prime, the ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$ obtained by reducing $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ modulo the prime ideal $(p)$ is a Principal Ideal Domain, since the coeffiencets lie in the field $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$.  This example shows that the quotient of a ring which is not a Principal Ideal Domain may be a Principal Ideal Domain.  To follow the ideal $(2,x)$ above in this example, note that if $p=2$, then the ideal $(2,x)$ reduces to the ideal $(x)$ in the quotient $\Bbb{Z}[x]/2\Bbb{Z}[x]$, which is a proper (maximal) ideal.  If $p\neq 2$, then $2$ is a unit in the quotient, so the ideal $(2,x)$ reduces to the entire ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$.
Questions
For above example, I am having a lot of trouble parsing the sentences.  Before anything, I want to say that I understand why the ideal $I$ consisting of polynomials with even constant terms is not a principal ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, and that the the meaning of the following notaations: $\Bbb{Z}[x]/2\Bbb{Z}[x]:=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2\Bbb{Z}[x]), \Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]:=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p\Bbb{Z}[x])$
The elements of $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $f(x)+ \langle p\Bbb{Z}[x] \rangle$.  I am not sure why the coeeficients lie in the field $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$ would make a difference. If $p$ is prime, what do the phrase: "....reducing $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ modulo the prime ideal $(p)$ is a Principal Ideal Domain" mean in math notation.
Next the sentence:  "if $p=2$, then the ideal $(2,x)$ reduces to the ideal $(x)$ in the quotient $\Bbb{Z}[x]/2\Bbb{Z}[x]$, which is a proper (maximal) ideal", does it mean since $(2,x)=(2)+(x)$, then $(2)+(x)\equiv (x) \pmod {(2x)}$?  Also, what is the differnece between a maximal ideal versus a proper maximal ideal?
Lastly, I am having trouble understanding the last phrase:  "If $p\neq 2$, then $2$ is a unit in the quotient, so the ideal $(2,x)$ reduces to the entire ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$."  why is 2 a unit in the quotient and also why then would the ideal $(2,x)$ reduces to the entire ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/p\Bbb{Z}[x]$?
Thank you in advance.

First paragraph of questions, what do you mean by "the ideal $I$ consisting of polynomials with constant terms" ?

@FançoisGatine i edited my post, I meant even constant terms.  Thank you for noticing.

For your first question, I believe the authors meant to say that the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x] / (p \Bbb Z [x])$ identifies with $\Bbb F_p [x] := (\Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z)[x]$: this is a ring of polynomials in one variable over a field, hence it is a PID. You can check that this identification holds by showing that the obvious map $\Bbb Z[x] \rightarrow \Bbb F_p [x]$ is surjective, and has kernel the ideal $(p \Bbb Z [x])$.
For your second question, we use the following fact:

Let $A$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $A$. Then the quotient map $\pi:A \rightarrow A/I$ induces a bijection between the sets $\{\text{ideals of $A$ containing $I$}\}$ and $\{\text{ideals of $A/I$}\}$.

This correspondence works as you'd expect, you can try to show it by hand. In particular, an ideal $J$ of $A$ containing $I$ corresponds to $\pi(J)$, which is an ideal of $A/I$ because $\pi$ is surjective (exercice). In our context, $A = \Bbb Z[x]$, $I = (2) = 2 \Bbb Z[x]$, $J = (2,x)$, and you can see that $\pi(J) = x \Bbb F_2[x] = (x)$, because 2 is mapped to 0 by $\pi$.
The term proper ideal simply means that the ideal is not the whole ring. The authors added the term "maximal" as a further remark that the image is a maximal ideal (which are, as part of the definition, proper). As far as I am aware, "proper maximal" does not mean anything.
If $p \neq 2$, letting $I = p \Bbb Z[x]$ as above, you can see this time that $\pi(2) \in \Bbb F_p[x]$ is the constant $\overline{2} \in \Bbb F_p$, which is therefore an invertible element, i.e. a unit, of $\Bbb F_p[x]$ (its inverse is $\overline{2}^{-1} \in \Bbb F_p$, which exists because $\Bbb F_p$ is a field and $\overline{2} \neq \overline{p}$ is not zero). In such a case, the ideal $\pi((2,x))$ contains $\overline{2}=\pi(2)$ which is invertible by what we just argued, so by multiplying by its inverse, we see that the ideal $\pi((2,x))$ contains $\overline{1}$: it is then the whole ring $\Bbb F_p[x]$.

$\Bbb{F}_p$ is only a field when $p\neq 2$ and $p$ is prime?  That is the reason why $2\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ and has an inverse.  Also, in the case where $p$ is prime, $\Bbb{F}_p$ is what is called a finite field?

The ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is indeed a field if and only if $n$ is a prime number, including 2 ($\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$ is a field, containing two elements). When this is the case, we usually denote $n$ by $p$, and yes, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field that is finite (so a finite field). In that case, to emphasize on the fact that it is a field (more than a ring), we write it as $\Bbb F_p$ (and also because it is quicker to write).

Notice that the integer $2$ is mapped to a nonzero element of $\Bbb F_p$ except when $p=2$. So when $p \neq 2$, $2$ is invertible in $\Bbb F_p$.

thank you so much for your detail write up.  Is it okay if I trouble you also about this recent post about notation.  There is a minor issue about the notation $j$ within the theorem reference in that post that I am not clear on. Thank you in advance.
